# Is there anyway to use generic map with Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer

Tags: spring-boot, redis, jackson, spring-webflux

In my application I need to cache several `Map<String, String>`. These `Map<String, String>` can have any number of keys and value but both will be Strings. I am trying to use this code.

```java
@Configuration
class RedisConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun redisOperations(factory: ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory): ReactiveRedisOperations<String, Map<String, String>> {
        val keySerializer = StringRedisSerializer()
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
        //               This is not working (cannot be called with the arguments supplied.) V   
        val valueSerializer: Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<Map<String, String>> = Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<Map<String, String>>(Map::class.java)
        val builder: RedisSerializationContextBuilder<String, Map<String, String>> = RedisSerializationContext.newSerializationContext(keySerializer)
        val context: RedisSerializationContext<String, Map<String, String>> = builder.value(valueSerializer).build()
        return ReactiveRedisTemplate(factory, context)
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic types could be used with `Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer` but you need to construct `JavaType` using `ObjectMapper`

```
objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {})
```

Here is a code in java you can adapt to Kotlin

```
var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

StringRedisSerializer keySerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();
Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<Map<String, String>> valueSerializer =
        new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {}));
RedisSerializationContext<String, Map<String, String>> context =
        RedisSerializationContext.<String, Map<String, String>>newSerializationContext(keySerializer)
                .value(valueSerializer)
                .build();
```